# Why is my modal opening on the bottom of page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have built a modal and inserted it into my code, however whenever I press the button that is supposed to open it up it goes to the bottom of the page. It is supposed to be on top of the rest of the page with a blurry bg, per say, but it just goes to the bottom of the page and it isn't even properly formatted. Here is an image.

[image]

Here is the code for that, the navbar and their css, and the modal js file.

https://repl.it/repls/GrubbyInsubstantialAutosketch

```
<body>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
      <nav>
        <div class="menu-center">


        <input type="checkbox"id="check">
        <label for="check">
          <i class="fas fa-bars" id="btn"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-times" id="cancel"></i>
        </label>
        <img src="logo-solo.png" >
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" class="active" > Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#quem-somos" >Quem somos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#onde-atuamos">Onde  Atuamos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#servicos">Servicos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Depoimentos">Depoimentos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Comecando">comecando</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sac">Contacte-nos</a></li>
        <a  href="https://www.instagram.com/mmtuniversity_oficial/" class="fa fa-instagram"  target="_blank"></a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuf2KhhA8Ub3hcSgfaziiDw" class="fa fa-youtube" target="_blank"></a>
         <a class="cta" rel="modal:open" href="#ex1" key="login" id="myBtn">Acessar</a>


      </ul>
</div>
     </nav>
     <script src="scroll.js"></script>









      <script type="text/javascript">
              document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
                    anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

          document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
              behavior: 'smooth'
              });
        });
        });

      </script>




                <div class="modal" id="modalContainer">
     <div class="container" id="myModal">
       <div class="form-container sign-up-container">
         <form action="#">
           <h1>MMT University</h1>
           <span>Se registre para começar</span>
           <input type="text" placeholder="Usuário" />
           <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
           <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
           <input type="password" placeholder="Repita a sua senha" />
           <button>Registrar</button>
         </form>
       </div>
       <div class="form-container sign-in-container">
         <form action="#">
           <h1>Acessar</h1>

           <span>Acesse a MMT University</span>
           <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
           <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
           <a href="#">Esqueceu a senha?</a>
           <button>Acessar</button>
         </form>
       </div>
       <div class="overlay-container">
         <div class="overlay">
           <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
             <h1>Bem vindo!</h1>
             <p>Para continuar aprendendo, acesse a sua conta!</p>
             <button class="ghost" id="signIn">Sign In</button>
           </div>
           <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
             <h1>MMT University!</h1>
             <p>Se registre para entrar na melhor universidade trading do mundo.</p>
             <button class="ghost" id="signUp">Registre-se</button>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
 <script src="modal.js"></script>

    </body>
```

Here is my css file, that has both the navbar and the modal code.

```
/*I could not add the justify content tag, it made my navbar disappear, this is my navbars css*/


body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;

}

nav {
  height: 10vh;
  background: #05031b;
  opacity: 0.85;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

nav img {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  margin-left: 5vh;
  margin-top: 11px;
}

.social-media-icons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 8vh;
  margin-right: 5vh;

}

.fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.fa-youtube {
  background: #05031b;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 40px;

}

.fa-instagram {
  background:  #05031b;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-right: 5vh;

}

nav ul{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;

}

nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 5px 50px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}



nav ul li a{
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 6px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}



nav ul li a:before{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(220,52,52);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: transform .4s linear;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

nav ul li a:hover:before{
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: left;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;


}

nav ul li a:hover{
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease0;
  color: rgb(220,52,52);
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;

}

nav .active a:hover {
  color: rgb(220,52,52);
}
nav .active a {
  color: rgb(220,52,52);
}
#menu-center {
    width: 980px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: rgb(220,52,52);
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
#menu-center ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    color: rgb(220,52,52);
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
#menu-center ul li a{
        padding: 32px 40px;
    color: rgb(220,52,52);
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
#menu-center ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -4px;
    display: inline;
    color: rgb(220,52,52);
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;

}
.active, #menu-center ul li a:hover  {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: rgb(220,52,52);
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);

}
 a {
  color: rgb(220,52,52);
}

#quem-somos {
  color: rgb(220,52,52);
}

.cta {

  padding: 9px 18px;
  background-color: rgb(220,52,52);
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #edf0f1;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cta:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 0.8);
}

label #btn,
label #cancel{
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
  float: right;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;

}

#check{
  display: none;
}



/*This is the modals css*/




h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    margin: 20px 0 30px;
}

span {
    font-size: 12px;
}

a {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

button {
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(220,52,52);
    background-color: rgb(220,52,52);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px 45px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: transform 80ms ease-in;
}

button:active {
    transform: scale(0.95);
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

button.ghost {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgb(220,52,52);
}

form {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 50px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

input {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: none;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.container-form {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25),
    0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 768px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 480px;
}

.form-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.sign-in-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-in-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

.sign-up-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-up-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
    animation: show 0.6s;
}

@keyframes show {
    0%, 49.99% {
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    50%, 100% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 5;
    }
}
.close {
  /* Position it in the top right corner outside of the modal */
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Close button on hover */
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)}
  to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}

@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {transform: scale(0)}
  to {transform: scale(1)}
}
.overlay-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-container{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.overlay {
    background:  #05031b;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #05031b, #05031b);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #05031b, #05031b);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay {
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

.overlay-panel {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(-20%);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.overlay-right {
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-right {
    transform: translateX(20%);
}

.social-container {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.social-container a {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 5px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;    /* position it so that fills the screen, but doesn't move with it */
  top: 0;             /* position this element at the top...                  */
  left: 0;            /* ...left corner of the page...                        */
  width: 100%;        /* ...and set both the width                            */
  height: 100%;       /* ...and height to 100%, so that the element fills the entire page */
  z-index: 99999;     /* set the z-index to a high enough number so that this element is positioned on top of all other elements */
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7); /* set the background to black with some transparency, so you can see through it */

  /* The following simply centers the modal within this container */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Now this is the modal.js, what controls the modals functions.

```
//Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var modal_container  = document.getElementById("modalContainer")
modal_container.style.display = "none";


window.onclick = function (event) {
  console.log(event.target)
  if(event.target.id == "myBtn") {
    modal_container.style.display = "flex"
  }
  else if (modal !== event.target && !modal.contains(event.target)) {
    modal_container.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the z-index attribute in CSS? You could also examine and mess around with it more in the dev tools of whatever browser you're using.

Comment: please share your code here in a working code snippet. otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: @berkobienb Could you recommend dev tools? I use chrome btw. Also, where would I add that z-index? To the modal? the container? Thanks

Comment: @MihaiT You have a link on the bottom of the post, but I just added it either way. Thank you for your comment

Comment: the link in the bottom of the post, does not look anything like your picture when run

Comment: @MihaiT set the style="z-index: 2" of the modal container. Mess around with it here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex

Comment: I said a working code snippet. not a copy paste of code that doesn't show any ' modal '

Answer (score 0):

You set an event handler for all links with `href` starting with '#' to scroll smoothly into view, but the `href` of the button that activates your modal windows is "#ex1". There is no "ex1" section in the document, which causes the script error.

A quick solution is to remove "#ex1" from the href attribute.

```
<a class="cta" rel="modal:open" href="" key="login" id="myBtn">Acessar</a>
```

Comment: I did that, but now whenever I press the button a modal pops up, but as if it were something wrong with my css. I added the code above, if you could give if a look please

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to. The modal window isn't opening on the bottom of the page in my browser.

Comment: I just added an edit with how it is showing up, if you could please check it out. Thank you mate

Comment: You'll have to be specific. Your new repl.it snippet still contains "#ex1" in `href`.